# How to Create Table from Irregular Length Element in R

Tags: r, excel

I'm new with R and seek some digestible guidance. I wish to create data.frame so I can create column and establish variables in my data. I start with exporting url into R and save into Excel;

```
data <- read.delim("http://weather.uwyo.edu/cgi-bin/wyowx.fcgi?
    TYPE=sflist&DATE=20170303&HOUR=current&UNITS=M&STATION=wmkd", 
    fill = TRUE, header = TRUE,sep = "\t" stringsAsFactors = TRUE,
    na.strings = " ", strip.white = TRUE, nrows = 27, skip = 9)
write.xlsx(data, "E:/Self Tutorial/R/data.xls")
```

This data got missing value somewhere in the middle of element thus make the length irregular. Due to irregular length I use write.table instead of data.frame.
As 1st attempt, in global environment, data exist in R value(NULL) not in R data;

```
dat.table = write.table(data)
str(dat.table) # just checking #result NULL?
```

try again

```
dat.table = write.table(data,"E:/Self Tutorial/R/data.xls", sep = "\t", quote = FALSE)
dat.table ##print nothing
```

remove sep =

```
dat.table = write.table(data,"E:/Self Tutorial/R/data.xls", quote = FALSE
dat.table ##print nothing
```

since its not working, I try read.table

```
dat.read <- read.table("E:/Self Tutorial/R/data.xls", header = T, sep = "\t")
```

Data loaded in R console, but as expected with irregular column distribution, (??even though I already use {na.strings = " ", strip.white = TRUE} in read.delim argument)

What should I understand from this mistake, and which is it. Thank you.

Comment: `write.table` does not create an object in R - it writes a file to your hard disk.  It seems your first line `read.delim` loads the data into an R data frame called `data`. Look at `str(data)`. Exporting to Excel with `write.xlsx`, or to a CSV or TXT file with `write.table` is only necessary if you want to save the data for later.

Comment: @Gregor, right. I need to use to use it later.

Comment: That's great. So then use `write.table` to write the file out. But don't assign the result in R: `anything = write.table(...)` will never make sense. If you want to check the result of `write.table`, look for the file on your hard drive.

Comment: @Gregor, I see.  thank you